# How to generate random numbers with assigned probability?

Tags: matlab

How to generate a matrix (40x10000) of random numbers between 1 and 100 with specific probabilities p1=Prob(1),p2=Prob(2), ... ,p100=Prob(100)?

Comment: Probably that array is too  big

Comment: no problem, I can wait for the result!

Comment: I mean proably is too big for Matlab. Anyway, what do you mean by specific probability? What is Prob(10)?

Comment: Prob(10)=the probability of having 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) with weights

```
h = 40; w = 10000;
out = reshape( randsample( numel(Prob), h*w, true, Prob ), [h w] );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I noticed that for the columns there are repetitive values. is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @bzak what do you mean by that? each column has 40 samples (out of 100) and it is not unlikely that some of these values would repreat themselfs. Do you want each column to contain unique 40 values out of the possible 100? the distribution of these 40 values might not agree with `Prob`...

Comment: I noticed that there are values ​​which appears several times even if they have a probability less than others that are unique

Comment: @bzak you should have enough samples for estimation: do `n = hist( out(:), 1:numel(Prob) ); n = n / numel(out); plot( [n(:), Prob(:)] );legend('empirical','Prob');` how similar are the two graphs?

Comment: the empirical curve oscillates around Prob, but very close.

Comment: @bzak, then I don't suppose there's much you can do: the function `randsample` produces a valid sample from the desired distribution...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the stats toolbox, you can do this longhand. Something like this should work:

```
thresholds = cumsum(Prob);
starter = rand(40, 10000);
finalAnswer = starter * 0 + 1; % initialize them all to be 1
for idx = 2:100
  finalAnswer(starter > (thresholds(idx - 1)) & starter <= thresholds(idx)) = idx;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

with the **Stats Toolbox** you can create a Multinomial distribution with specified probabilities and then use random to generate a sample with the required size.

with the vector of probabilites `Prob`

```
Pd = makedist('Multinomial','Probabilities',Prob);
out = random(Pd,4,10000);
```

Comment: how i can use Stats Toolbox?

Comment: sorry that should have said "if you have the Stats toolbox", it is an additional toolbox by MathWorks, (would require a licence for it, at an additional cost - however many organisations have it)... if the above doesn't work you probably don't have it and its almost certainly not worth it for this....